# How to calculate percentage of total in user retention chart

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a user weekly retention chart. I have data in form

```
count weeks_from_first_login
100   0
50    1
20    2
10    3
etc
```

And I'd like to add a third column which would give me the share of users who logged in on a specific week:

```
count weeks_from_first_login share
100   0                     100%
50    1                     50%
20    2                     20% 
etc
```

How would I do it? If it helps, the date is originally in form

```
device_id start_time etc
23123123  2019-08-20 07:01:17.185 UTC etc
```

And I've done something like

```
select firstlogin
, logindate
, round(timestamp_diff(logindate, firstlogin,day)/7) as weeks_from_first_login
, id
, app_id from (
select first_value(start_time) 
   over(partition by device_id 
   order by start_time asc) 
   as firstlogin
, device_id
, app_id
, start_time 
, timestamp_trunc(start_time , day) as logindate 
, device_id as id
  from `sessions.sessions` 
)
```

to get the data to the current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your sample query has to do with your question.  But based on the data in your question, you can just use:

```
select weeks_from_first_login, count,
       count / max(count) over () as ratio
from t;
```

This assumes that the biggest count is the first one.  You can also use `first_value()` or conditional aggregation:

```
select weeks_from_first_login, count,
       count / first_value(count) over (order by weeks_from_first_login) as ratio
from t;
```